# How to build a routing protocol in omnet++

Tags: c++, networking, routes, omnet++, inet

I am new to omnet++ and i am learning the software. Can any one guide me how to build routing protocol using omnet++. And do i have to use inet or castalia for building the same.

Comment: Maybe you should start learning OMNeT++ by doing the Tic Toc tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

As Princy Rakholiya mentioned you should first do the tic toc example of OMNeT++:
https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/

Then take a look at the Wireless INET tutorial:
https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/

Personal experience has shown that taking an INET example (take a routing algorithm which is implemented yet and similar to yours) and change it the way you need it, is a good way to start.

After that you should be able to ask in a more specific way.